# Vagrant hangs at "DEBUG loader: Configuration loaded successfully, finalizing and returning"

Tags: ruby, vagrant

I've been chugging along editing my Vagrantfile and working towards an automated install of LAMP and Wordpress and suddenly `vagrant up`, `vagrant destroy` just hang, with no feedback. Moments earlier it worked fine, with no problem

I though maybe I messed up my Vagrantfile, but runnning a different file has exactly the same problem

I switched debugging on by

```
export VAGRANT_LOG="debug"
```

And now when I run `vagrant up` I get the following, even if I wait half an hour it never gets beyond "Configuration loaded successfully, finalizing and returning" Can anyone help? I have already upgraded Vagrant and VirtualBox up to the latest versions. I am running OSX 10.9.2

```
 INFO global: Vagrant version: 1.6.2
 INFO global: Ruby version: 2.0.0
 INFO global: RubyGems version: 2.0.14
 INFO global: VAGRANT_EXECUTABLE="/Applications/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.2/bin/vagrant"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_LOG="debug"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_INSTALLER_EMBEDDED_DIR="/Applications/Vagrant/bin/../embedded"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_INSTALLER_VERSION="2"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_DETECTED_OS="Darwin"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_INSTALLER_ENV="1"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_INTERNAL_BUNDLERIZED="1"
 INFO global: Plugins:
 INFO global:   - addressable = 2.3.6
 INFO global:   - multipart-post = 2.0.0
 INFO global:   - faraday = 0.9.0
 INFO global:   - berkshelf-api-client = 1.2.0
 INFO global:   - buff-extensions = 0.5.0
 INFO global:   - hashie = 2.1.1
 INFO global:   - varia_model = 0.3.2
 INFO global:   - buff-config = 0.4.0
 INFO global:   - buff-ruby_engine = 0.1.0
 INFO global:   - buff-shell_out = 0.1.1
 INFO global:   - hitimes = 1.2.1
 INFO global:   - timers = 2.0.0
 INFO global:   - celluloid = 0.16.0.pre
 INFO global:   - nio4r = 1.0.0
 INFO global:   - celluloid-io = 0.16.0.pre
 INFO global:   - minitar = 0.5.4
 INFO global:   - sawyer = 0.5.4
 INFO global:   - octokit = 3.1.0
 INFO global:   - retryable = 1.3.5
 INFO global:   - buff-ignore = 1.1.1
 INFO global:   - erubis = 2.7.0
 INFO global:   - json = 1.8.1
 INFO global:   - mixlib-log = 1.6.0
 INFO global:   - mixlib-authentication = 1.3.0
 INFO global:   - net-http-persistent = 2.9.4
 INFO global:   - semverse = 1.1.0
 INFO global:   - ridley = 3.1.0
 INFO global:   - dep-selector-libgecode = 1.0.0
 INFO global:   - ffi = 1.9.3
 INFO global:   - dep_selector = 1.0.3
 INFO global:   - solve = 1.2.0
 INFO global:   - thor = 0.19.1
 INFO global:   - berkshelf = 3.1.1
 INFO global:   - bundler = 1.6.2
 INFO global:   - mime-types = 2.2
 INFO global:   - rest-client = 1.6.7
 INFO global:   - vagrant-berkshelf = 2.0.1
 INFO global:   - vagrant-hostmanager = 1.4.0
 INFO global:   - vagrant-login = 1.0.1
 INFO global:   - vagrant-omnibus = 1.4.1
 INFO global:   - vagrant-share = 1.0.1
```

...

```
DEBUG cli: Invoking command class: VagrantPlugins::CommandUp::Command []
DEBUG command: 'Up' each target VM...
 INFO loader: Set :root = #<Pathname:/Users/dantagg/code/connected_wp/Vagrant-LAMP-Stack/Vagrantfile>
DEBUG loader: Populating proc cache for #<Pathname:/Users/dantagg/code/connected_wp/Vagrant-LAMP-Stack/Vagrantfile>
DEBUG loader: Load procs for pathname: /Users/dantagg/code/connected_wp/Vagrant-LAMP-Stack/Vagrantfile
 INFO loader: Loading configuration in order: [:home, :root]
DEBUG loader: Loading from: root (evaluating)
DEBUG provisioner: Provisioner defined: hostmanager
DEBUG provisioner: Provisioner defined: chef_solo
DEBUG loader: Configuration loaded successfully, finalizing and returning
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a lock file

```
Berksfile.lock
```

that caused the problem.

Comment: could you tell me where is the file? I didn't find it but I have the same issue now. Thanks